# Eclipse - Run program from a different project

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

In LibGDX all your programming is done in the "core" project, but that project can only be run as Gradle Builds (which does nothing, as far as I know). So instead you must click on the dropdown arrow and run from the DesktopLauncher (or run the "desktop" project, if it is your first time running the project). Is there any way I can automate that so I only have to click the green arrow? I know it's only a minor inconvenience, but I'd like to get rid of it, if possible, nonetheless.

Comment: if the local runtime runs in java, get process explorer and examine the command line used to launch the java process. you can then copy paste that command into a run configuration.

Comment: @LorenzoBoccaccia How would I do that in Eclipse?